# ask user for input and use that input in math module

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I ask an user for input. Then I assign that input to variable var to use it for the math module:

```
var = "pi"
print(math.var)
```

But then I get an attribute error. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: You _could_ use `getattr(math, var)` but why on earth would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an attribute error because Python will try to access the `var` attribute of the `math` module, which does not exist. It will not try to evaluate `var` as a variable.

Assuming that `var` is the name of some member of the `math` module (or some other module, or an object), you could use the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) builtin to get the value of that attribute.

```
>>> var = "pi"
>>> getattr(math, var)
3.141592653589793
```

Comment: `getattr()` is a better and safer solution than using `eval()`. Voting up this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) for this. Here we're constantly asking user for `math`'s attribute until he provide existing one.

```
import math

inp = input('Enter math attribute: ')
while not getattr(math, inp, None):
    inp = input('Please enter valid attribute: ')

print(getattr(math, inp))
```

**Output:**

```
python3 get_math.py 
Enter math attribute: adc
Please enter valid attribute: pi
3.141592653589793
```

Answer (score 0):

Check work fine:

```
import math

var = 'pi'

print(math.__getattribute__(var))
```

Output:

```
3.141592653589793
```